ReplaceIndexed function
I would like a replaceAllIndexed in the spirit of MapIndexed where there is an easy way to access the counter in the rule. I understand I can write say
count = 0;
{1, 1, 1} /. i_Integer :> (count += 1)

but I had to introduce a global counting variable which isn't that nice.
Is it possible to write some function that automatically uses a locally scoped counting variable, for example with the following syntax:
replaceAllIndexed[expr_, ruleFunction_]

where the ruleFunction[i_Integer] gives a Rule or RuleDelayed for a given integer i.

The following almost does what I want. It is basically replaceRepeatedIndexed:
ClearAll[replaceOnce];
replaceOnce[expr_,rule_]:=Catch[ReplacePart[expr,FirstPosition[expr,rule[[1]],Throw[expr]]->rule[[2]]]];
replaceOnce[rule_][expr_]:=replaceOnce[expr,rule];

ClearAll[replaceAllIndexed];
replaceAllIndexed[expr_,ruleFunction_]:=Module[{count=0},
    FixedPoint[(count+=1;replaceOnce[ruleFunction[count]][#])&,expr]
];


You can do {1, 1, 1} /. Module[{count = 0}, i_Integer :> (count += 1)] to avoid defining a global variable.
